# Access wordpress function by url parameter

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin. And trying to call with name by calling in URL like:

```
http://example.com/order?view=part1
```

then it should call back my `part1` function and if I enter

```
http://example.com/order?view=part2
```

then it should call back my `part2` function.

I have written these functions in plugin php file.

I don't have much idea about such thing as I am beginner in WordPress development.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: you need to explain what these functions do, so you can use the appropriate hook

Comment: these functions belongs to different views of plugin in wordpress

Comment: Are these functions make a redirect, load templates, echo to Frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this in your plugin.

```
if(isset($_GET['view']) && ($_GET['view']=="part1")){
    function_part1();
}else if(isset($_GET['view']) && ($_GET['view']=="part2")){
    function_part2();
}
```